# Force a named range to refer to a literal string

Tags: vba, excel

I'm using the following VBA code to reproduce the problem:

```
ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add "Test", RefersTo:="1-2"
```

The resulting named range refers to "=42767" instead of ="1-2"

[image]

It seems that it is doing some calculation and setting RefersTo to the result.
How can I force the range to refer to the literal string "1-2"

Another example (although not as troublesome)

```
ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add "Test", RefersTo:="123"
```

Results in `RefersTo=123` instead of the desired `RefersTo="123"` (number vs text)

Entering the RefersTo through the GUI with quotes works fine but doing it through VBA it gets altered

Comment: Maybe: `ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add "Test", RefersTo:=Chr(34) & "1-2" & Chr(34)`

Comment: That results in a string containing quotation marks... It looks like including an '=' in-front works though!

Comment: FWIW - your existing `1-2` is being treated as `1 February 2017` (i.e. day number 42767).

Answer (score 1):

The following code works

```
ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add "test", RefersTo:= "=" & Chr(34) & "1-2" & Chr(34)
```

You can replace "1-2" with any string variable or literal that you want to to be forced into the ranged name as text

Comment: Yes, or `RefersTo:= "=""1-2"""`. That is it.